# Flip Image Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, plugins

I am trying to flip images in a simple HTML script. I have found this [jQuery plugin](http://nnattawat.github.io/flip/) which from the examples does what I need to do.

However, When I try to do it in [Brackets](http://brackets.io/), nothing happens.

I have read questions with a title like mine, but the effects I want is not in the plugins used in their questions.

This is the code I made is pretty simple **(trivial!)**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <title>Test Flip</title>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nnattawat/flip/master/dist/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="card"> 
          <div > 
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/" id="top">
          </div> 
          <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/" id="bottom">
          </div> 
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $("#top").flip({axis: 'x', 
                            trigger: 'hover'})

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the plugin docs it says 
How to use
In your HTML file, create a `<div>` with two `<div>s` inside with class `.front` and `.back`  You didn't do that.  Also you are trying to flip the top image and not the card, by calling `$("#top").flip` instead of `$("#card").flip`

Comment: Are `.front` and `.back` classes from the plugin itself ? @James

Comment: .front and .back is how the plugin knows which content is supposed to be on the front and which content is supposed to be on the back of the card.  It looks like the plugin supports other class names if you tell it, but by default that's what it looks for.

Comment: @James Thanks a lot it worked. At the beginning I didn't understand the what the plugin mean with the classes assigned. But thanks to you, I figured it out. Thanks again.

Comment: You can add an answer so I accept it. @James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have told the plugin which content within your "card" div you want to appear on the front and on the back. By default the plugin looks for "front" and "back" classnames set as follows:

```
<div id='card'>
  <div class='front'>This is what appears on the front</div>
  <div class='back'>This is what appears on the back</div>
</div>
```

Also make sure you invoke the .flip function on the wrapping element (ie, id=='card')

```
$("#card").flip(params...);
```